# internet explorer driver without the need of PATH variable

Tags: node.js, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, npm

Is there a way to use an Internet Explorer Driver without having to set the PATH variable? The reason is for easy project setup. It is so much easier to not have to install a path variable for each browser driver. I looked over the web in several areas and wasn't able to find a solution of any sort. I was able to get the chromedriver working properly:

```
var chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
var path = require('chromedriver').path;

var service = new chrome.ServiceBuilder(path).build();
chrome.setDefaultService(service);

var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
   withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).
   build();
```

I tried doing the samething for the iedriver found [here](https://github.com/barretts/node-iedriver) at this git repository and ran into an issue where the selenium-webdriver/ie.js doesn't contain a service builder as the selenium-webdriver/chrome.js file does. I am quite new to node.js and would appreciate any help, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, **yes**. If an executable named `IEDriverServer.exe` exists in the current working directory (which is explicitly checked), then that instance will be chosen and the `PATH` check bypassed (the error message is a little misleading).

You can follow the logic in the Selenium source [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/7d062439bd4beba33fcc08a68a6213db43efcd76/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/ie.js#L363) and [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/7d062439bd4beba33fcc08a68a6213db43efcd76/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/io/index.js#L210).

Comment: Thank You for the answer. I was easily able to locate the current working directory with process.cwd() and then placing the .exe in that directory. I can change the directory by using process.chdir(directory);

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the exact IEDriver path using this:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var ie = require('selenium-webdriver/ie');
var path = require('iedriver').path;

driver = new webdriver.Builder()
  .setIeOptions(new ie.Options().setExtractPath(path))
  .build();
```

or can just do this since the iedriver is already inside your node_modules considering that you've installed using [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iedriver)

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

driver = new webdriver.Builder()
  .forBrowser('internet explorer')
  .build();
```